# CRM Custom Workflow Errors on AutoMapper System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a project (CRM custom workflow) that works locally but on deploy throws System.TypeInitializationException.

Now to clarify my local scenario is using a MVC test harness where deployment is to a (on prem) Msoft Dynamics CRM 2013 server.

Two important pieces to the puzzle. I am using AutoMapper and ilmerge. Ilmerge DOESN'T appear to be connected in any way but wanted to still make it known.

My project structure is that the customer workflow is one project in the solution. I then have a core functionality library in the same solution.

So my Custom Workflow references Core Library. Core Library references AutoMapper.

BOTH project have ilmerge. My thought/understanding was ilmerge would build core library references (Automapper) into a single dll...and appears to do so.

I then reference that single core library in the custom workflow project and again using ilmerge combine the two (core library & workflow) into one workflow library.

Again this works from my local test harness but upon deployment fails at the very first reference to AutoMapper.

So in the workflow:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
{
    ....code...
    tracingService.Trace("PreInit");
    CoreCRM.Initialize.Start();
    tracingService.Trace("PostInit");
    .....more code....
}
```

The core initialization is registering the map like this:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(CoreCRM.Initialize), "Start")]
namespace CoreCRM
{

   public class Initialize
   {
      public static void Start()
      {
         Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
         {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .FindAllDerivedTypes<Profile>()
                    .ForEach(match =>
                      {
                         cfg.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(match) as Profile);
                      });
        });
      }
   }
}
```

I am using PreApplicationStartMethod as crm is a web based solution and the error comes from within Start() so it seems to me it is working.

The error and full stack is:

```
Plugin Trace:

PreInit



Error Message:

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Unexpected exception from plug-in 
(Execute): CrmWorkflow: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions' threw an exception.
at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context)
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ProxyCustomActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
```

One thought I had..but it is grasping at straws..is perhaps my custom workflow has to reference AutoMapper...but that doesn't make sense.

The system event log shows nothing. I am at a loss and would appreciate any direction or input...even just additional tracing / debugging techniques.

Thank You

Comment: Did you make sure the DLL was registered in non-sandbox mode?Although CRM is a web app the workflows run in a separate Windows service, so I don't think `PreApplicationStartMethod` is going to do anything. I recommend a quick debug session in VS to catch the exception so you can see the inner exception - that should give you more detail.

Comment: Debug in VS would be awesome...but not sure how. The only thing I could think of was to MOQ all the CMR services.

Comment: If it is a Workflow you just need to attach to the Async service in VS and trigger the Workflow in CRM. Mocking won't help, this isn't unit testing - there is, more likely, a conflict between how the custom code operates and what CRM is allowing.